# Proper QUuid usage in Qt ? (7-Zip DLL usage problems (QLibrary, QUuid GUID conversion, interfaces))

Tags: qt, dll, interface, guid, qlibrary

I'm trying to write a program that would use 7-Zip DLL for reading files from inside archive files (7z, zip etc).

Here's where I'm so far:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QUuid>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  

#include "7z910/CPP/7zip/Archive/IArchive.h"
#include "7z910/CPP/7zip/IStream.h"
#include "MyCom.h"

// {23170F69-40C1-278A-1000-000110070000}  
QUuid CLSID_CFormat7z(0x23170F69, 0x40C1, 0x278A, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00);  

typedef int (*CreateObjectFunc)(  
 const GUID *clsID,  
 const GUID *interfaceID,  
 void **outObject);  

void readFileInArchive()  
{  
 QLibrary myLib("7z.dll");  
 CreateObjectFunc myFunction = (CreateObjectFunc)myLib.resolve("CreateObject");  
 if (myFunction == 0) {  
  cout << "CreateObject resolve failed!";  
  return;  
 }  
 else {  
  cout << "CreateObject resolved";  
 }  
 CMyComPtr<IOutArchive> outArchive;  
 myFunction(&CLSID_CFormat7z, &IID_IOutArchive, (void **)&outArchive);  
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);  
 readFileInArchive();  
 return a.exec();  
}
```

Trying to build that in Qt Creator will lead to following error:

> cannot convert 'QUuid*' to 'const GUID*' in argument passing

How should QUuid be correctly used in this context?

Also, being a C++ and Qt newbie I haven't yet quite grasped templates or interfaces, so overall I'm having trouble getting through these first steps. If someone could give tips or even example code on how for example an image file could be extracted from ZIP file (to be shown in Qt GUI later on*), I would highly appreciate that.

- My main goal at the moment is to write a program with GUI for selecting archive files containing image files (PNG, JPG etc) and displaying those files one at a time in the GUI. A Qt based CDisplayEx in short.

Comment: As an alternative to you solution, you may build in to your source code zlib + quazip libraries, create simple buffer folder for image files, and then unzip with quazip functions needed files which will be viewed in future. As least for me this variant worked.

Comment: QComicBook seems to use this method by extracting images from archive to temporary folder.
http://github.com/stolowski/QComicBook
It does the job, but I'm currently interested in placing extracted images to RAM in the same way as CDisplayEx does (cdisplayex.exe reserves more RAM at runtime when it opens an archive file).

Thanks for the comment, hadn't thought about zlib or quazip.

Comment: Damn, < and > cut the code example short, here's the cut out part in readFileInArchive():

if (myFunction == 0) {  
   cout << "CreateObject resolve failed!";  
   return;  
}  
else {  
   cout << "CreateObject resolved";  
}  
   CMyComPtr<IOutArchive> outArchive;  
   myFunction(&CLSID_CFormat7z, &IID_IOutArchive, (void **)&outArchive);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly cast QUuid to GUID:

```
QUuid boo;
GUID uid = static_cast<GUID>(boo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use some conversion between the 2 types.

Looking at Qt documentation, I found that there is a GUID operator that transform a QUuid to a Windows GUID : http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/quuid.html#operator-GUID

Of course, this is not cross-plateform.

Comment: How is QUuid::operator GUID () const used?

Comment: ..likely something very basic.. Haven't yet understood the correct syntax for this. Qt documentation doesn't have examples on how it is used, so the monkey in me hasn't seen how it should be used.

Comment: @whipsnap: It allows implicit conversion from one type to another.  Basically, you should be able to make a GUID variable from the QUuid, then pass it: QUuid qid; /* ... */ GUID gid( qid );  The reason it doesn't work for what you are doing is that it is trying to convert a pointer, not an actual object.

Comment: @whipsnap I was confused how it is used as well because it is an `operator` function. That means it operates on Quuid object instead of object calling it. Normal function is `obj.foo()` but if `foo()` is operator than `foo(obj)` is how it is used.