# How to assign GUID value to a variable?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, guid

I'm working with code where a GUID is defined like this:

```
DEFINE_GUID( GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DISK,
             0x53f56307L, 0xb6bf, 0x11d0, 0x94, 0xf2,
             0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0x1e, 0xfb, 0x8b );
```

I want to change the value and use a different class GUID from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) where it is is defined as `{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}`

How to I set to this value or create a new GUID variable which is set to this value?

Based on another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544348/initialise-a-guid-variable-how) I tried but that doesn't work

```
GUID USB_GUID = GUID {"{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}"}
```

Note, this GUID is used by a windows API later in my code:

```
if ( ! SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces( hDevInfo, 
                                    NULL,
                                    &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DISK,
                                    dwIndex, &spdid ))
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [QUuid](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html) class (as you are tagging this question as related to Qt):

It has threesconstructors that may solve your problem:

```
QUuid(uint l, ushort w1, ushort w2, uchar b1, uchar b2, uchar b3, uchar b4, uchar b5, uchar b6, uchar b7, uchar b8)
QUuid(const QString & text)
QUuid(const GUID & guid)
```

I think both `QUuid( "0xA5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED" )` and `QUuid( GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DISK )` should create you a QUuid correctly setup.

If you need to convert the QUUid back to a GUID (to send it to SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces) for instance, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685352/3336423), you simply need to do:

```
QUuid boo( "0xA5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED" );
GUID uid = static_cast<GUID>(boo);
```

Comment: I need it to feed it to a windows API namely `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` I don't see any conversion to GUID if I use it!

Comment: Why you did not mention that in the OP?

Comment: This worked but I noticed there is `operator` function `GUID` which should return windows GUID but I have't heard of a function and operator before. Simplying call it does't build. Any idea how to make that work?

Comment: It's a cast operator, that can be used this way: `GUID uid = (GUID)boo` or `GUID uid = static_cast<GUID>(boo)`. So as you see, the static cast will use this operator.

Comment: @zadane: In my post I'm giving the code converting QUuid to GUID.